# Object data values retrieved from a Vue fetch composable are undefined in main

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-cli-3

I am struggling to properly create  and retrieve data from a "useFetch" composable. My fetch composable looks like this:

```
import { reactive, Ref } from "vue";
import axios from "axios";

export default function useFetch(
  requestId: Ref<number>,
  fetchType: string,
) {

  const queryId = requestId;

  const data: any = reactive([]);

  const fetchRequest = fetchType;

  switch (fetchRequest) {
    case "storeInfo":
      fetchStoreInfo();
      break;
  }

  function fetchStoreInfo() {
    const infoQuery = `SELECT * FROM t_store_info WHERE ss_store_id = ${queryId.value}`;
    axios
      .post(`url`, query, {
        headers: {
          "content-type": "text/plain",
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        data.value = response.data[0];
      })
  }

  return { data };
}
```

And my main:

```
let requestId = ref(0);
let storeData = reactive([]);

async function getStoreInfo() {
  try {
    storeData = useFetch(requestId, "storeInfo");
  } finally {
    console.log(storeData); //this prints to console the object with all the right data inside
    console.log(storeData.data); // prints same as above, but unable to go deeper from here
    console.log(storeData.data.store_id); //this is undefined
    console.log(storeData.data[0]); // this is undefined
    console.log(storeData.data.value); // this is undefined
    console.log(storeData.data[0].value); //this throws an error
  }
}
```

The fetched object structure looks like this, if it helps:

```
{
    "storeId": 1,
    "storeName": "Store Name Inc",
    "storeAddress": "address here",
}
```

I am trying to access data from the storeData object like storeData.storeName, but it is always undefined. How do I access the properties properly when they're retrieved from a composable? What's the right way to retrieve fetched data from a composable?

My question was closed as duplicate but the question regarding asynchronous functions doesn't seem to apply here.

I am able to access the data after the call, so the data itself isn't undefined, I just can't seem to access the properties of the data inside. The *properties* are undefined. When I console log the data object itself, I see the data all there, as illustrated above.

I have deliberately went to the link provided and tried their methods of using async/await and promises to ensure the data is filled and exists before calling it. It still causes the same issue where the data **object** is there, and if I log the object I see its properties, I'm just using the wrong method of logging/accessing **just** the data properties. I'm sure the answer must be very simple and I'm just using the wrong syntax to access the property.